# How can I convert my server date into this format Eg "Mar 13, 2018 4:54:17 PM" using javascript using timeZone JS

Tags: javascript

I have my server date in this format "2018-03-12 18:18:26". How can I convert this into this format "Mar 13, 2018 4:54:17 PM" with respect to given timezone in javascript using timezone JS

Answer (score 0):

As a simple way, just use JS native [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) class:

```
new Date("2018-03-12 18:18:26");
// output = Mon Mar 12 2018 18:18:26 GMT+0200 (FLE Standard Time)
```

you can store the date into variable, and get some specific values to construct your own format

```
var date = new Date("2018-03-12 18:18:26");
var formattedDate = date.getMonth() + " " + date.getDate() + ...
```

If you need something more complex, try to use [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/) library. It has a lot of additional options.

Comment: Thank you. Can you help me with how I can use timeZone JS to convert this with respect to given time zone

Comment: If you are asking about some `time-zone.js` library, I think it's better just to read their documentation. I'm not familiar with this. But you also can do something similar with Date class [toLocaleString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString), for example `new Date("2018-03-12 18:18:26").toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: "America/New_York"})`